# X-axis log-scale conversion ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a chart in ggplot2 using data from the gapminder package in RStudio. I am curious how to convert the horizontal axis to log scale. I did use the function scale_x_continuous but after running the code the graph disappears.

```
ggplot(data = gapminder07) + geom_point(mapping = aes(x = gdpPercap, y = lifeExp))
p <- ggplot(gapminder07, aes(x = gdpPercap, y=lifeExp, label = country))
p + geom_text()
p + scale_x_continuous(trans = 'log10')
```

Edit* The same issue occurs when adding a fitted line. The line appears but the data points disappear.

```
ggplot(data = gapminder07) + geom_point(mapping = aes(x = gdpPercap, y = lifeExp))
p <- ggplot(gapminder07, aes(x = gdpPercap, y=lifeExp, label = country))
p + geom_text()
p + geom_smooth()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created a `ggplot` object with your first `ggplot()` call, and then you stored your second `ggplot` object into the variable `p`. In your next line, when you called `p + geom_text()`, you overwrite the first `ggplot` object with your second `ggplot` object with just `geom_text()`.

Essentially, you called this code:

```
ggplot(data = gapminder07) + geom_point(mapping = aes(x = gdpPercap, y = lifeExp))
ggplot(gapminder07, aes(x = gdpPercap, y=lifeExp, label = country)) + geom_text()
ggplot(gapminder07, aes(x = gdpPercap, y=lifeExp, label = country)) + scale_x_continuous(trans = 'log10')
```

Each time you call `p + ...`, you overwrite the previous plot. Instead, you should do something like...

```
ggplot(gapminder::gapminder, aes(x = gdpPercap, y = lifeExp, color = country)) + geom_point() + scale_x_continuous(trans = 'log10')
```

I removed the `geom_text()` call since the countries' names just covered up the entire plot. I got [image: this figure] after running that code.